# Benchmark function for Dispersive Flies Optimisation algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, function, benchmarking

The problem: have an array of 5 numbers in range of 0-50. Trying to "guess" this number using DFO algorithm (a nature inspired, population based algorithm). Now this algorithm mostly used for optimisation problems, and in every implementation must contain a test function (also called fitness, or benchmark function) of which evaluates the current result. These are usually Rastigrin, Sphere, Ackley, etc functions. In my case I am having hard time finding the right one, since this is just matter of comparison: agent A comes with a guess, if any numbers are matching, then pass the info to the population, and they will use with their guess, or not using those aren't matching.

Example array: [1,3,9, 23, 49]
Guess of Agent A: [2,4,9,11,33]
Agent B's, and C's guess is based on A's experience: since 9 is included, they include it, and will not use 2,4, 11,33 since they know these numbers are invalid.
Therefore guess of Agent B: [5, 6, 7, 9, 13, 32]

The algo would running until they replicate the original array of numbers with less possible guess.

So how do I benchmark these intermediate results?

Comment: Do you mean benchmark as in time, performance?  Or in statistics, to see how quickly it's converging? 
 Like root-mean-square error, or sum-of-absolute-differences?  (The [benchmarking] tag unfortunately gets used for both.)

Comment: Benchmarking in this context (and this kind of algorithms) means the evaluation of the intermediate solutions how fit they are for future work. (Therefore they also called tens function, how fit they are.)